# How does Photo Caller ID work?

Tags: sms, photos, caller-id, contact-photo

Sometimes someone will call me and their photo will show as the phone rings. In the cases I'm referring to I've never added a photo to the contact---somehow the phone picks up their image over the Internet.

I'd like to register my photo in such a place, but how does it work?

I have had both iPhone and Android users call me and sometimes I get their "Photo Caller ID" for lack of a better term.

My phone is an HTC m8 running LineageOS 14.1.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: On Android go to settings -> Google -> manage Google account -> personal data. Then there is an option to upload your image

Comment: So does Google do the lookup on the phone number to show on my screen?  I'd like to add my business # to the lookup and show my logo which isn't a cell phone.

Comment: You can register your number on Truecaller because that is most used caller app, it has option to add picture, business information and it shows on caller id who uses Truecaller